# String scan/split on CRLF with a regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Whats the best way for split a string on a CRLF delimiter but with a possible incomplete message at the end (no CRLF)?

```
buf1 = "msg1\r\nmsg2\nmsg3\r\nmsg_no_CRLF"
buf2 = "msg1\r\nmsg2\nmsg3\r\nmsg4\r\n"

a = buf1.scan(/.*\r?\n|.*/)
>>> ["msg1\r\n", "msg2\n", "msg3\r\n", "msg_no_CRLF", ""]

a = buf2.scan(/.*\r?\n|.*/)
>>> ["msg1\r\n", "msg2\n", "msg3\r\n", "msg4\r\n", ""]
```

I try to obtain an empty string or an incomplete message for the last item of the array.

```
>>> ["msg1\r\n", "msg2\n", "msg3\r\n", "msg_no_CRLF"]
>>> buf1 = a.last #  "" or "msg_no_CRLF"
```

EDIT: I have this method:

```
def read
  msgs = []
  @buffer << @socket.read_nonblock(1024)
  while @buffer.slice!(/(.*)\r?\n/)
    msgs << $1
  end
  msgs
end
```

That works but i try to do the same in two lines with scan or split.

The method must return an array of complete messages (all the parts before each CRLF).

```
@buffer = "msg1\r\nmsg2\r\n" 
# Ok, return ["msg1", "msg2"] and @buffer is set to ""

@buffer = "msg1\r\nmsg2"
# incomplete msg2, return ["msg1"] and @buffer is set to "msg2" for the next read.
```

Sorry for my English, it's difficult to explain correctly.

Comment: Why is there a `\m` in the two strings? `\msg3`?

Answer (score 0):

One another possibility with slice.

```
msgs = []
while buf1.slice!(/(.*?)\r?\n/)
  msgs << $1
end

# msgs: ["msg1", "msg2", "msg3"]
# buf1: "msg_no_CRLF"

# msgs: ["msg1", "msg2", "msg3", "msg4"]
# buf2: ""
```

Any ideas to do something like that?

```
msgs = buf1.scan(//)
buf1 = msgs.pop
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like:

```
buf1 = "msg1\r\nmsg2\n\msg3\r\nmsg_no_CRLF"
buf2 = "msg1\r\nmsg2\n\msg3\r\nmsg4\r\n"

buf1.split(/([\r\n]+)/) # => ["msg1", "\r\n", "msg2", "\n", "msg3", "\r\n", "msg_no_CRLF"]
buf2.split(/([\r\n]+)/) # => ["msg1", "\r\n", "msg2", "\n", "msg3", "\r\n", "msg4", "\r\n"]

buf1.split(/([\r\n]+)/).each_slice(2).map(&:join) 
# => ["msg1\r\n", "msg2\n", "msg3\r\n", "msg_no_CRLF"]

buf2.split(/([\r\n]+)/).each_slice(2).map(&:join) 
# => ["msg1\r\n", "msg2\n", "msg3\r\n", "msg4\r\n"]
```